# knockout.js Refresh data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've wrote following fiece of code and I got stuck in this point - I'm asking server for some data and moreover, I recieve this piece of data. Now, all I want to do is to update my collection.

```
function GameViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.colors = [];   // I had to create additional lists that contain the same data as observableArrays. Is it necessery?
    self.storages = [];

    self.colorList = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.storageList = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON("api/Color", function (allData) {
        _.each(allData, function (color) {
            var newColor = new Color(color.Name, color.ColorHash, color.ColorHex, color.Amount, color.HourIncrement, color.IncrementBonus, color.VisitIncrement, color.VisitFrequency);
            self.colorList.push(newColor);
            self.colors.push(newColor);
        });

        $.getJSON("api/Storage", function (storageData) {
            _.each(storageData, function (storage) {
                var foundColor = _.find(allData, function (color) { return color.ColorHash == storage.ColorHash; });
                var newStorage = new Capacity(storage.ColorHash, foundColor.ColorHex, foundColor.Amount, storage.ActualStorage);
                self.storageList.push(newStorage);
                self.storages.push(newStorage);
            });
        });
    });

    self.enlargeStorage = function (storage) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "api/Storage",
            data: { color: storage.colorHash },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
            }
        })
        .done(function (returnObj) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.storages.length; i++) {
                if (self.storages[i].colorHash == returnObj.ColorHash) {
                    self.storages[i].actualMaxAmount = returnObj.ActualStorage;
                    break;
                }
            }

            self.storageList = ko.observableArray(self.storages);
        });
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new GameViewModel());
```

The view code:

```
 <ul data-bind="foreach: storageList">
        <li>
            <table class="colorStorageContainer">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="colorStorageSize">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: colorHex }"></td>
                                <td>Capacity</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: actualMaxAmount"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: actualAmountPerctentage"></td>
                                <td><button data-bind="click: $parent.enlargeStorage">Enlarge</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

...

The data doesn't refresh. it looks like nothing happened. Debugger doesn't show any exceptions.

How to refresh self.storageList?

Comment: Are you sure that the call back of api/Storage is called  and that storageData contains an array ?

Comment: 100% sure. I set breakpoint in api/Storage code, and breakpoint in self.storageList = ko.observableArray(self.storages);. Both breakpoints fire and I can see recieved data on client side.

Comment: Can you post the view ?

Comment: Why do you created two versions of arrays ?

Comment: Becouse in click event storageList was empty. I don't know why, but to solve this I created additional, traditional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the problem :

```
self.storageList = ko.observableArray(self.storages);
```

it should be :

```
self.storageList(self.storages);
```

You should't replace the observableArray. Because only the old one (the original observableArray) is bound to the view.

You don't need two versions of data.
Try this :

```
.done(function (returnObj) {
    // notice the (), this evaluates the observableArray and get the inner array
    var storages =  self.storageList();

     for (var i = 0; i < storages.length; i++) {
        if (storages[i].colorHash == returnObj.ColorHash) {
            storages[i].actualMaxAmount = returnObj.ActualStorage;
            break;
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between this two lines, but I've copied second line and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Fka this should work, but try the following: `self.storageList(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.storages))`

Comment: @Armand storages is not an observable so it doesn't need to be unwrapped.

Comment: @Fka yeah I saw after further inspection of what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

I found problem with this:

```
 if (self.storages[i].colorHash == returnObj.ColorHash)
```

The JavaScript can't compare this two values. returnObj has two properties, debugger displays this values, but if i put mouse over ColorHash, type is undefinied. I've tried with _.find() underscore method, but I thought this was reason of non-refreshing.